# How to change the properties of a contextmenu in a datatemplate in WP7?

Tags: c#, silverlight, windows-phone-7, xaml, silverlight-toolkit

**What I want**
change the properties(e.g. background) of a context menu in a datatemplate in the runtime from the code behind.

**What is the XAML**

```
<DataTemplate x:Key="ListsDataTemplate">
    <StackPanel x:Name="stackPanel" Margin="0,0,0,10">
        <toolkit:ContextMenuService.ContextMenu> 
            <toolkit:ContextMenu x:Name="myMenu" IsFadeEnabled="False" IsZoomEnabled="False">
                        <toolkit:MenuItem x:Name="edit" Header="{Binding LocalStrings.bt_menu_Edit, Source={StaticResource LocalizedResources}}" Click="menuItemEdit_Click" />
                        <toolkit:MenuItem x:Name="postpone" Header="{Binding LocalStrings.bt_menu_Postpone, Source={StaticResource LocalizedResources}}" Click="menuItemPostpone_Click" />
                        <toolkit:MenuItem x:Name="email" Header="{Binding LocalStrings.bt_menu_Email, Source={StaticResource LocalizedResources}}" Click="menuItemEmail_Click" />
                        <toolkit:MenuItem x:Name="sms" Header="{Binding LocalStrings.bt_menu_Sms, Source={StaticResource LocalizedResources}}" Click="menuItemSMS_Click" />                        
                </toolkit:ContextMenu> 
        </toolkit:ContextMenuService.ContextMenu>

        <ListBox    
            HorizontalAlignment="Left" 
            DataContext="{Binding}" 
            ItemTemplate="{StaticResource ListsDataTemplate}" 
            VerticalAlignment="Top" 
            Width="432" 
            Margin="0,81,0,0" 
            x:Name="myListBox">
        </ListBox>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add a `Loaded="myMenu_Loaded"` handler to `myMenu`, and in that handler declare `var myMenu = (ContextMenu)sender;`.

Since myMenu is in a DataTemplate and is a template for creating objects rather than the instance that will actually be used on the page, no field is auto-generated for it.

Comment: When I type "my", the IntelliSense doesn't show "myMenu" for me. How can I access it? I think the reason is because it is in a datatemplate.

Comment: I didn't notice that it is in a DataTemplate.  I've revised my answer.

Comment: it is a very interesting solution -_-